# jQuery load in event handler - how to manipulate several attributes of event element when load is complete?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This should be fairly basic jQuery/Ajax, but I'm just getting started and stumped on how to accomplish a simple task. I have a right mouse click event handler that fires on a particular class of images on my page. In the event handler, I want to collect some data from the server, and use this data to populate a few attributes of the element that was clicked. The data fetch goes OK, but I'm not clear on how to specify the element that needs to be manipulated to the callback function.
This:

```
 <script> 
 $(document).on("contextmenu",".title",function(event) {
 loadurl="/ajax/title.php5?url="+$(this).attr("id");
 $.get(loadurl,function(data,function(data)
                           {$(this).attr("src","/i/title.gif"); 
                            $(this).attr("title",data);
                           })
 $(this).attr("title",ttl);
 return false;
 });
 </script>
```

does not work, because "this" no longer refers to the  element inside the callback function. So how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<script> 
 $(document).on("contextmenu",".title",function(event) {
     $here = $(this);
     loadurl="/ajax/title.php5?url="+$(this).attr("id");
     $.get(loadurl,function(data,function(data)
     {
            $here.attr("src","/i/title.gif"); 
            $here.attr("title",data);
     })
     $here.attr("title",ttl);
     return false;
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I thought I had tried that, too. But come to think of it, I think I tried $here=this, instead.